# Number format of ticks in log log axis won't change to scientific notation `a x 10^b`, 'a' real, 'b' integer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, ticks

I'm trying to set the number format of the ticks in a `loglogaxis` to the scientific notation `a x 10^b` ($a \cdot 10^{b}$ in LaTeX, `a` a real number and `b` an integer), but it's not working.

I use the code

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}
        [
            tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci zerofill,precision=5}, % WHY DOES THIS NOT WORK?
            xtick={1,95}
        ]
            \addplot[no marks,domain=10^0:10^5] {x};
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but the `tick label style` command does not seem to change anything.

[image]

The `10^1.98` should be `9.5*10^1`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Log axes have a different style see 4.15.1 in the manual

Comment: Your MWE gives tick number format as you desired. Even without your it formatting declaration.

Comment: @Zarko In scientific notation, `a` is a real number and `b` is an integer. I've modified my code to emphasize the problem with the notation.

Comment: With your MWE I can't reproduce your image. It has only a part around ``xaxis=yaxis=10^0``. The ``9.5*10^1`` is seem to be an extra tick, which is not define ... I suspect that your figure was obtain with other program as you provided as MWE

Comment: @Zarko I added `,domain=10^0:10^5` to the options of the `\addplot` command. Try it now.

Comment: @percusse Actually, I found `log number format code` in section 4.13.2 of the PGFplots manual Revision 1.12 (2015/01/31). Is this what you meant? When I add `log number format code/.code={\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci zerofill,precision=3]{\tick}},` to the axis options, the format is correct, but the numbers correspond to `log(\tick)` and not to `\tick`. When I try `log number format code/.code={\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci zerofill,precision=3]{exp(\tick)}},` to fix this, I get a `Could not parse input` error. Do you perhaps know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}
        [   
            log number format code/.code=
            {
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
                \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}
                \pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
            },
            xtick={1,95}
        ]
            \addplot[no marks,domain=10^0:10^5] {x};
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

does the job!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad that meanwhile (when I was occupied with my regular tasks :-)) you find a solution for your problem. My proposition require more "hand work", but it is quit simple:

```
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}
        [
            xtick={2,95},
            xticklabels={$2\cdot10^0$,$9.5\cdot10^1$}
        ]
            \addplot[no marks,domain=10^0:10^5] {x};
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: Obviously ;). But the whole idea was to automate this process for the case in which someone (like me ;)) has a lot of `loglogaxis` figures. Doing this for the dozens of figures I denote in my papers with your 'hand work' solution would be rather tedious :D. Anyways, the case is solved. The solution I proposed above seems to work just fine.

Comment: I suspect your intention. If you look examples on pages 280/281 in pgf manual, you will see that in logaxis with ticks on position rounded to ten the conversion is done as you like, but if the values is not rounded to ten, then pgfplots convert numbers as you observe. This is to my opinion at least misconception or bug in pgfplots package. Till to now I didnt find in manual (for version 1.12) described something similar to your solution. I congratulation you for it!