# `every loglogaxis/.append style` not working in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, ticks

I'm trying to apply to scientific notation as constructed in

[Number format of ticks in log log axis won't change to scientific notation `a x 10^b`, 'a' real, 'b' integer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245939/number-format-of-ticks-in-log-log-axis-wont-change-to-scientific-notation-a-x)

to all the `loglogaxis` in my document by using

```
\pgfplotsset
{   
    every loglogaxis/.append style=
    {
        log number format code/.code=
        {
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
            \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}
            \pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci zerofill,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        }
    }
}
```

in the preamble of my `LaTeX` document. It, however, seems to be completely ignored, see figure below.

How do I fix this?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset
{   
    compat=newest,
    every loglogaxis/.append style=
    {
        log number format code/.code=
        {
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
            \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}
            \pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci zerofill,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        }
    } % DOESN'T WORK!
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}
        [   
                name=plot_left,
            xtick={1,95},
            %log number format code/.code={\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}\pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}} % WORKS!
        ]
            \addplot[no marks,domain=10^0:10^3] {x};
        \end{loglogaxis}
        \begin{loglogaxis}
        [   
            name=plot_right,
            at={($(plot_left.east)+(20mm,0)$)},
            anchor=west,
            xtick={1,95},
            %log number format code/.code={\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}\pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}} % WORKS!
        ]
            \addplot[no marks,domain=10^0:10^3] {exp(x)};
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. The key name is `every loglog axis`.

Regardless of the code, don't remove the `%` at the end of lines in the code block. You will get spurious spaces otherwise.

Comment: Pffffffff what a pathetic mistake. The compiler does not even give an error with the faulty `every loglogaxis`. My bad....:(. Thanks!

Comment: @Adriaan It is not faulty it is just a key that is not used. If you use the handler `.. style={}` you actually create it if it is not already defined regardless it is used or not later.